# Create plainn HTML> with Visual Web Studio 2010 with NO ASPX within

Tags: visual-studio, web

Can I use Visual Web Studio Express from Microsoft and create web pages that will run on Apache servers?

I mean without the "code behind" stuff, just plain CMS website?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still on VS2008 Pro, but I assume it's the same on VS2010 Express. Just open a plain html file (can be empty) or create a new one. You don't have to create a project or solution to edit it. You should be able to use preview pane, code pane, the css property tools, etc.

Comment: And then I can upload these web ".htms " pages as is on my host LAMP server, thats it?

Comment: Yeah, sure. HTML is just plain text after all.